# PuppeteerSharp: How to both enable request interception and caching at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I would like to both enable request interception and also enable caching at the same time. However, in digging through the [PuppeteerSharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/) source code, I see that there seems to be deliberate code to make these two properties mutually exclusive. Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1. Why are caching and request interception mutually exclusive in PuppeteerSharp?
2. Is it possible to override this so that both can be enabled at the same time? How?

Here is additional information:

See https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/NetworkManager.cs for all screenshots below.

This method indicates that `UpdateProtocolCacheDisabledAsync()` is called when `Fetch.enable` is called, which is the internal [DevTools method](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable) used for request interception.

[image]

And caching is in fact disabled when `_protocolRequestInterceptionEnabled` is set to `true` when `_userRequestInterceptionEnabled` is also set to `true`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is an upstream issue related to that https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4620

Comment: @hardkoded Do you see any issues with this solution? https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1185

Comment: I honestly don't know. What I do know is that pptr# should behave like pptr. I would try to change that in pptr and see what they think about it.